# File Write Permission Issue in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to write image files to the specified folder, but I always receive this error:

Unable to open file
"C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\code_version_1.0\myImages"
for writing.  You may not have
write permission.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

```
for i=1:numberOfFiles 
    filename=fileList{i};
img=imread(filename,'jpg');
image = imresize(img, [150,150]);

folder='C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\code_version_1.0\myImages';
  if ~exist(folder,'dir')
    mkdir(folder);
  end
imwrite(image,folder,'jpg');
```

end

Comment: the folder you give to imwrite does not contain a file name at the end !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `imwrite` has an invalid second parameter. You gave it a folder when it is asking for a file path.

Here's a possible work-around:

```
outfile = fullfile(folder, 'output.jpg');
imwrite(image, outfile, 'jpg');
```

Comment: just curious, where is that form of the `imwrite` function documented?

Comment: @KevinDTimm: Second parameter is "Name of the output file including the file extension". QA passed the directory where he wants the file.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Try `help imwrite`

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `imwrite` like this :

```
imwrite(image,'C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\code_version_1.0\myImages\image.jpg');
```

you can after append things as you like. check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html?refresh=true#inputarg_filename)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check if the folder exists or not:

> `folder='C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\code_version_1.0\myImages';`

If it doesn't exist ,folder wont be created automatically and will give the same error :You may not have write permission.